# Bold Greek letters in achemso

Tags: fonts, pdftex, bold, greek, achemso

I'm having trouble producing a bold capital "Pi" while using the **achemso** document class.  The only success that I've had is by using `\bm{\Pi}` which produces an ugly result akin to "poor man's bold", `\pmb`.  I think I've narrowed it down to **achemso**'s use of **mathptmx** that causes this problem.  Here's a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{bm}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\text{normal:  } \Pi \\
&\text{mathbf:  } \mathbf{\Pi} \\
&\text{bm:  } \bm{\Pi}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way of producing a clean-looking bold capital "Pi" that will be compatible with **achemso** and **pdfLaTeX**?

Comment: With `mathptmx` there is no boldface math.

Comment: @egreg -- Are you sure about this claim? If one types `\boldsymbol{\Pi}` rather than `\mathbf{\Pi}` in the MWE above, LaTeX has no problem generating a nice bold `\Pi` symbol.

Comment: @Mico That was a general comment; in the particular case it seems that `achemso` is doing some nasty things, because `\Pi` is taken from the Symbol font that can be emboldened.

Comment: You get  a correct bold `\Pi` if `bm` is loaded with `\RequirePackage` *before* `\documentclass{achemso}`. I've asked the class maintainer what he thinks.

Comment: @egreg I can confirm that, as you suggest, using `\RequirePackage{bm}` before the `\documentclass{achemso}` does produce a bold Pi.  Oddly, it appears to change the font slightly.  The bold Pi appears with "flat" serifs where as the normal font has "tapered" serifs.  You can see these two different Pi symbols in the image posted by @Boris, `mathbf` vs `bm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathptmx is an older package, which lacks many features provided by newer Times-compatible font packages.  Newtxtext and newtxmath are a very good alternative.

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,achemso}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{bm}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\text{normal:  } \Pi \\
&\text{mathbf:  } \mathbf{\Pi} \\
&\text{bm:  } \bm{\Pi}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that works great!  Does anyone know if this fix is OK for ACS journal submission?

Comment: `mathptmx` is indeed an older package, but a lack of bold math symbols is not one of its shortcomings. If one types `\boldsymbol{\Pi}` instead of `\mathbf{\Pi}`, there is no problem.

Comment: @tarheels You can always upload a PDF. I don't have access to the full detail of the TeX system installed on the ACS servers, so the only way to find out if it will work there with `newtxmath` is to submit and see!

Comment: @Micro I tried `\boldsymbol{\Pi}`.  When using `amsmath` only, `\boldsymbol{\Pi}` yields the same result as `\Pi`.  When using `amsmath` and `bm`, `\boldsymbol{\Pi}` yields the same result as `\bm{\Pi}` (which is a "poor man's bold").  If there's something I'm missing that's causing this issue, I'd be glad to try it.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I think I'll just have to see what happens at submission.  Not being able to produce a bold greek letter is quite a drawback, especially when trying to stay consistent with previous work, so I don't think I have much of a choice.

Comment: @tarheels As I mentioned to egreg in the chat system, I'm in favour of dropping the use of `mathptmx` as the ACS have made style changes to their print work. Perhaps I'll just go for this!